# git interpret-trailers at the end of a file

Tags: git

i am using git [interpret-trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) and would like to add a trailer at the end of a file like so

```bash
$ cat ./test
# foo

# bar

# baz

$ git interpret-trailers --in-place --where end --unfold --trailer "should-appear-at: bottom" ./test

$ cat ./test
# foo

should-appear-at: bottom

# bar

# baz
```

as you can see `should-appear-at: bottom` does not appear in the last line (end) of the `test` file but after the first comment (lines starting with `#` considered as comment).

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be specifying a token/value for the `--trailer` option? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers#Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt---trailerlttokengtltvaluegt

Comment: If you remove the `#`'s, `should-appear-at: bottom` is inserted at the bottom. So evidently the `#`s are getting some special interpretation by `git-interpret-trailers`

Comment: @Brian61354270 I think `#` is a comment and doesn't get added to git commits.

Comment: @evolutionxbox re 1: it looks like they are. That's what `"should-appear-at: bottom"` is per syntax in the docs, no? re: 2, indeed, I was just pointing out that the issue has to do with `git-interpret-trailers` is handling them

Comment: Try adding some non-commented content between `# bar` and `# baz`. `git-interpret-trailers` will change the trailer location to be after that content. It looks like `git-interpret-trailers` doesn't care about trailing comments after the trailer. It just makes sure that the trailer comes after all of the commit message content